# JBAS014883: No resource definition is registered - Local JBoss failing

Tags: java, gradle, jboss

I have a Gradle project that I'm trying to deploy locally with `gradlew stopServers deploy startServers` but it fails with this error:

```
:components/verification-ear:stopServers
Stopping server: localhost/server-three
Failed to get the list of the operation properties: "JBAS014883: No resource definition is registered for address [
    ("host" => "localhost"),
    ("server-config" => "server-three")
]"
:components/verification-ear:stopServers FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

I don't understand why this is throwing an error. I have servers 1 & 2 shut off while 3 is running full-ha. My `JBOSS_HOME` variable is correct and I'm running in domain mode from the JBoss Home bin.